# Two CSS Questions - Removing H1 line break on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here's my h1 problem:[link removed]
i need the h1 to blend into the paragraphs perfectly for seo purposes. the tags are around Long Island.

I have the css set to h1{display: inline;padding:0;margin:0;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;} still breaking... before. i tried adding similar stuff to "< p >" but it completely took out all the breaks, i still need some breaks!

Comment: why not combine your H1 and #banner into a class? .brand {…} and it could also be because your breaking your Block elements. try setting H1 back to a block and use margin:  0 auto; on your H1… apparently ive developed the inability to read. Sorry, my comment provides little assistance.

Comment: For your banner problem, sometimes it's the dropshadow; does it work without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can just use a H1. use a span to style specific words within your h1.

```
<h1>Welcome! My name is Nancy Lewis and I’m from <span>Long Island</span></h1>
```

Then u can style the words Long Island as you like

```
h1 span {font-weight:700} /*or whatever you like*/
```

for the second example, try to put margin yo for your body

```
body {margin:0}
```

Comment: but will spiders pick up the span only as the h1 or the entire sentence? kinda confused

Comment: all what's inside the h1 tag is considered as an h1. If you need to have on Long Island as an h1, then you should try to give it a class with display:inline as well as for the p that precede it and the New York. example here : http://jsfiddle.net/rAcDz/

Answer (score 2):

Both H1 and P are block level elements. In order to get the effect you want, both P and H1 need to have their styles set to `display: inline;`.

Try:

CSS:

```
.inline { display: inline; }
```

HTML:

```
<p class="inline"> Welcome! My name is Nancy Lewis and I’m from </p>
<h1 class="inline"> Long Island </h1>
<p class="inline"> , New York. </p>
```

Comment: You *can't* nest the H1 inside the P.

Comment: I did have a disclaimer but really should be suggesting such things anyway, it's been edited out.

Comment: This worked. Except the paragraph after that wouldn't break a line. I just made another class and added margin-top. Looks seamless.

Answer (score 1):

So you need the `h1` and it's immediate following `p` element to be inline. Simple!

The `h1`:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

The immediate following `p`:

```
h1 + p {
    display: inline;
}
```

What's the `+` up there? It's the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) `+`. Go ahead, click the link.

That's it! But, of course, there's no need to repeat yourself. Stick the two together, and you get:

```
h1,
h1 + p {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's a fiddle (actually, a "tinkerbin"): http://tinkerbin.com/jy3uoWX9